# Изменение размера окна выбранной страницы

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, resize, qstackedwidget

[image: Размер]

Вот тут при запуске программы, размер окна нужный, но если запустить main файл, то получается, вот так:

[image: Не тот размер]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
################################## Тут вызовы  ui файлов

from Apex import Ui_MainWindow # Основное окно начало
from weaponsUIrepeat import Ui_other # окно Оружия
from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1 # окно пистолета wedomiy
from pistoll import Ui_MainWindow2 # окно пистолеты
from p2020 import Ui_MainWindow3 # окно пистолета p2020
from RE import Ui_MainWindow4 # окно пистолета RE 
from pp import Ui_MainWindow5 # окно пистолеты пулемёты 
from SMG import Ui_MainWindow6 # окно Пп сменщик 
from ISH import Ui_MainWindow7 # окно Пп ищейка
from R99 import Ui_MainWindow8 # окно Пп R99
from VOLT import Ui_MainWindow9 # окно Пп R99

class Apexhelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Apexhelper, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)


class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):                            # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):                                  # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()     
        self.setupUi(self)

class pistoll (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pistoll, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class P2020 (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P2020, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class RE(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RE, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class PP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow5):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PP, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class SMG(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow6):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SMG, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class ISH(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow7):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ISH, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class R99(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow8):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R99, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class VOLT(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow9):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VOLT, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)             


# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)      #создали центральный виджет  
        # Начало класса apexHelper
        self.apexHelper = Apexhelper(self) # экземпляр класса ApexHelper
        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon) 
        # конец класса apexHelper

        # Начало класса Weapon
        self.weapon = Weapon() # экземпляр класса Weapon
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.pistol.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        self.weapon.PistolP.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса Weapon

        # Начало класса pistoll
        self.pist = pistoll() #экземпляр класса pistoll
        self.pist.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi) 
        self.pist.backk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pist.p2020.clicked.connect(self.gotop2020)
        self.pist.re.clicked.connect(self.gotoRE)
        # конец класса pistoll

        # начало класса R99
        self.r99 = R99()
        self.r99.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса R99

        # начало класса VOLT
        self.volt = VOLT()
        self.volt.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса VOLT


        # начало класса SMG
        self.smg = SMG()
        self.smg.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса SMG

        # начало класса ISH
        self.ish = ISH()
        self.ish.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса ISH

        # Начало класса p2020
        self.p2020 = P2020()
        self.p2020.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса p2020

        # Начало класса RE
        self.re = RE()
        self.re.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса RE

        # Начало класса Пистолеты-полемёты
        self.pp = PP() #экземпляр класса PP
        self.pp.backkk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pp.smen.clicked.connect(self.gotosmg)
        self.pp.ihek.clicked.connect(self.gotoish)
        self.pp.R99.clicked.connect(self.gotoR99)
        self.pp.volt.clicked.connect(self.gotovolt)
        # Конец класса Пистолеты-полемёты



        # Начало класса wedomi
        self.wedomi = Wedomi() # экземпляр класса Wedomi    
        self.wedomi.backtoweapon.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)                          
        # Конец класса wedomi

        #Начало виджетов
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()      # QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов                                                  # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)    # 1   self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi) # 2 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pist) #3 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.p2020) #4 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.re) #5 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pp) #6 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.smg) #7 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.ish)#8 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.r99)#9 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.volt)#10 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10) 
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
           


        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ????????????????????????????????????
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
    
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg'))                         
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('rtg.jpg'))                             
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('wedomiy.png'))       
        elif w == 3:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ty.jpg'))
        elif w == 4:   
            self.setWindowTitle('P2020')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('p2020.png'))
        elif w == 5:   
            self.setWindowTitle('RE-45 Auto')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('re.png'))
        elif w == 6:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol-P')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('fgh.png')) 
        elif w == 7:   
            self.setWindowTitle('SMG')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('SMG.png'))
        elif w == 8:   
            self.setWindowTitle('ISH')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ish.png'))
        elif w == 9:   
            self.setWindowTitle('R99')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('R99.png'))    
        elif w == 10:   
            self.setWindowTitle('VOLT')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Volt.png'))                                           

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotopistol(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotop2020(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotoRE(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoPP(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotosmg(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoish(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoR99(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotovolt(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                             # --- ApexHelper(), +++ MainWindow
    w.show()              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


# Первое окно, на его размеры ссылается второе окно в скринах ниже

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(230, 652)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.607143 rgba(76, 76, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(23, 23, 23, 255));\n"
"border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: black")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("gg.jpg"))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label)
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.weapon.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_14)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_13)
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_12)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_10)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_11)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 230, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ApexHelper"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оружия"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



# третий файл, который надо исправить 

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_other(object):
    def setupUi(self, other):
        other.setObjectName("other")
        other.resize(435, 572)
        other.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ravie")
        other.setFont(font)
        other.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(183, 96, 147);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(other)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 471, 241))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/nikpf/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/apexx/hqdefault.jpg"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 300, 241, 201))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/nikpf/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/apexx/hqdefault (1).jpg"))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 500, 81, 30))
        self.back.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.back.setFont(font)
        self.back.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.back.setObjectName("back")
        self.PistolP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PistolP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 271, 121, 31))
        self.PistolP.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.PistolP.setFont(font)
        self.PistolP.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.PistolP.setObjectName("PistolP")
        self.pistol = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pistol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 240, 121, 30))
        self.pistol.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pistol.setFont(font)
        self.pistol.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pistol.setObjectName("pistol")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 360, 121, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(172, 85, 140);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        other.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(other)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 435, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        other.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(other)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        other.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(other)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(other)

    def retranslateUi(self, other):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        other.setWindowTitle(_translate("other", "MainWindow"))
        self.back.setText(_translate("other", "Back"))
        self.PistolP.setText(_translate("other", "Submachine guns"))
        self.pistol.setText(_translate("other", "Pistol"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("other", "Weapons"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    other = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_other()
    ui.setupUi(other)
    other.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

![на этом ломается]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj77d.jpg)
То что закомменчено ломает, второе окно, а все последующие, запрещают менять размер начального окна

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Всё добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста.. Раньше всё было нормально и размер менялся. Но сейчас почему-то все размеры окон считываются с первого окна и почему-то не меняется

Comment: Если вам понадобится, я могу скопировать весь код из файлов и скинуть сюда

Comment: Если запускать файлы по отдельности, то всё ок... что-то с main файлом

Comment: @S.Nick Как сможете дайте знать

Comment: вы должны опубликовать все модули, которые позволять запустить ваше приложение и увидеть проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Я не могу скопировать весь код, слишком много символов

Comment: разместите ваш проект на  github

Comment: @S.Nick https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I3Dy38H4cUAqJaO3qAeczpnjQCxAlzTQ?usp=sharing Так быстрее ссылка на гугл диск

Comment: может и быстрее, но `Нет доступа`

Comment: @S.Nick Я не умею пользоваться гитхаб, но что-то получилось https://github.com/Nanoxia123/wednesday18_00

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I3Dy38H4cUAqJaO3qAeczpnjQCxAlzTQ?usp=sharing и вот открыл доступ

Comment: @S.Nick что-нибудь получилось?

Comment: @S.Nick, я вам ниже там написал, как будет время прочтите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил некоторые рекомендации для вас в тексте кода и отметил строки, которые добавил и на которые надо обратить внимание.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

#  Тут вызовы  ui файлов
from Apex import Ui_MainWindow                        # Основное окно начало
from weaponsUIrepeat import Ui_other                  # окно Оружия

from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1                    # окно пистолета wedomiy
from pistoll import Ui_MainWindow2 # окно пистолеты
from p2020 import Ui_MainWindow3 # окно пистолета p2020
from RE import Ui_MainWindow4 # окно пистолета RE 
from pp import Ui_MainWindow5 # окно пистолеты пулемёты 
from SMG import Ui_MainWindow6 # окно Пп сменщик 
from ISH import Ui_MainWindow7 # окно Пп ищейка
from R99 import Ui_MainWindow8 # окно Пп R99
from VOLT import Ui_MainWindow9 # окно Пп R99


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(230, 652)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.607143 rgba(76, 76, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(23, 23, 23, 255));\n"
"border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: black")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_2)
        
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("gg.jpg"))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label)
        
# weapon
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.weapon.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon)
        
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_14)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_13)
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_12)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_10)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_11)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #708090;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 230, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ApexHelper"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оружия"))
        
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        

class Apexhelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):     # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Apexhelper, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):        # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 


class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):              # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()     
        self.setupUi(self)

class pistoll (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pistoll, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class P2020 (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P2020, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class RE(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RE, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class PP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow5):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PP, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class SMG(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow6):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SMG, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class ISH(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow7):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ISH, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class R99(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow8):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R99, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class VOLT(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow9):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VOLT, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)             


# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)       
        # класс apexHelper
        self.apexHelper = Apexhelper(self) 
        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon) 

        # класс Weapon
        self.weapon = Weapon() 
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.pistol.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        self.weapon.PistolP.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса Weapon

        # Начало класса pistoll
        self.pist = pistoll() #экземпляр класса pistoll
        self.pist.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi) 
        self.pist.backk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pist.p2020.clicked.connect(self.gotop2020)
        self.pist.re.clicked.connect(self.gotoRE)
        # конец класса pistoll

        # начало класса R99
        self.r99 = R99()
        self.r99.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса R99

        # начало класса VOLT
        self.volt = VOLT()
        self.volt.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса VOLT

        # начало класса SMG
        self.smg = SMG()
        self.smg.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса SMG

        # начало класса ISH
        self.ish = ISH()
        self.ish.back11.clicked.connect(self.gotoPP)
        # конец класса ISH

        # Начало класса p2020
        self.p2020 = P2020()
        self.p2020.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса p2020

        # Начало класса RE
        self.re = RE()
        self.re.back1.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)
        # конец класса RE

        # Начало класса Пистолеты-полемёты
        self.pp = PP() #экземпляр класса PP
        self.pp.backkk.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)
        self.pp.smen.clicked.connect(self.gotosmg)
        self.pp.ihek.clicked.connect(self.gotoish)
        self.pp.R99.clicked.connect(self.gotoR99)
        self.pp.volt.clicked.connect(self.gotovolt)
        # Конец класса Пистолеты-полемёты

        # Начало класса wedomi
        self.wedomi = Wedomi() # экземпляр класса Wedomi    
        self.wedomi.backtoweapon.clicked.connect(self.gotopistol)                          
        # Конец класса wedomi

        #Начало виджетов
# НЕТ   QStackedWidget видно сразу несколько виджетов
# ДА    Класс QStackedWidget предоставляет стек виджетов,              !!!
#       в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.               !!!
        
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()                                                        # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper) # 0
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)     # 1   
        
        ''' # ВНИМАНИЕ !!! добавляете по ОДНОМУ и  
            # смотрите чтобы ничего не ломалось.
            # Если ломается исправляете форму соответствующего 
            # добавляемого виджета vvvvv и ставите подсказку размера 
            # в методе где у вас осуществляется переход на даннную страницу
            #                vvvvvvvvvvv
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi) # 2 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pist)   # 3 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.p2020)  # 4 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.re)     # 5 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.pp)     # 6 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.smg)    # 7 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.ish)    # 8 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.r99)    # 9 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.volt)   #10 self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        '''
        
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) # вроде можно без этого ?
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
    
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg')) 
            
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('rtg.jpg')) 
            
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('wedomiy.png')) 
            
        elif w == 3:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ty.jpg'))
        elif w == 4:   
            self.setWindowTitle('P2020')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('p2020.png'))
        elif w == 5:   
            self.setWindowTitle('RE-45 Auto')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('re.png'))
        elif w == 6:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Pistol-P')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('fgh.png')) 
        elif w == 7:   
            self.setWindowTitle('SMG')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('SMG.png'))
        elif w == 8:   
            self.setWindowTitle('ISH')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ish.png'))
        elif w == 9:   
            self.setWindowTitle('R99')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('R99.png'))    
        elif w == 10:   
            self.setWindowTitle('VOLT')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Volt.png'))                                           

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
# +++ 
        self.resize(230, 652)                                     # +++
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
# +++        
        self.resize(435, 572)                                      # +++
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotopistol(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotop2020(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(4)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotoRE(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(5)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoPP(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(6)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotosmg(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(7)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoish(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(8)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

    def gotoR99(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(9)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
    
    def gotovolt(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(10)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                    
    w.show()              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**weaponsUIrepeat.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_other(object):
    def setupUi(self, other):
        other.setObjectName("other")
        other.resize(435, 572)
        other.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Ravie")
        other.setFont(font)
        other.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(183, 96, 147);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(other)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

# вы как-то странно подгоняете геометрию    vvv     vvv  vvv
# при этом картинка hqdefault.jpg у вас имеет рахмеры 480x360
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 471, 241))
#        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 241))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("hqdefault.jpg"))      # 480x360
#        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("hqdefault.jpg").scaled(435, 320))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 300, 241, 201))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("hqdefault (1).jpg"))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 500, 81, 30))
        self.back.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.back.setFont(font)
        self.back.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.back.setObjectName("back")
        self.PistolP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PistolP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 271, 121, 31))
        self.PistolP.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.PistolP.setFont(font)
        self.PistolP.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.PistolP.setObjectName("PistolP")
        self.pistol = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pistol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 240, 121, 30))
        self.pistol.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pistol.setFont(font)
        self.pistol.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: #5c88cb;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 3px solid #65032c;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton: pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pistol.setObjectName("pistol")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 360, 121, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(172, 85, 140);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        other.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(other)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 435, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        other.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(other)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        other.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(other)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(other)

    def retranslateUi(self, other):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        other.setWindowTitle(_translate("other", "MainWindow"))
        self.back.setText(_translate("other", "Back"))
        self.PistolP.setText(_translate("other", "Submachine guns"))
        self.pistol.setText(_translate("other", "Pistol"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("other", "Weapons"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    other = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_other()
    ui.setupUi(other)
    other.show()
    print(f'other.geometry() = {other.geometry()}')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Self.resize, это изменение размера именно этого окна?

Comment: Вы изменили только main файл?

Comment: Могу ли я вас попросить, где можно все это прочитать и выучить? Просто про Self.resize я даже не знал

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Все написано в документации   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resize-1 , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: что-то не работает.. Но я указал self.resize

Comment: Вроде получилось, но размер можно уменьшить сильнее, можно ли как-то просто заблочить разрешение изменения окна?

Comment: Я добавил выше скрин шот